# count in model scopes() function

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to count the total matches found in my `scopes`, the scope works and returns every other column, except the `COUNT()`

```
   public function scopes()
        {
            return array(
                'test'=> array(
                        'alias' => 'd',
                        'select'=> array('d.id, d.picture, d.store, d.address, d.postcode, d.city, d.state, COUNT(*) AS totalAds'),
                        'join' => 'JOIN `ads` AS v',
                        'condition'=>'d.is_new="0" AND v.pending!="1" AND d.id = v.id',
                        'group'=>'v.id'
                ),
       }
```

in my view i'm trying to get the data using `$data->totalAds` but i get this error when i use this  `print_r($data->totalAds)`

The error i get is
`Property "Store.totalAds" is not defined.`

I'm using Yii 1.1.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error states, `totalAds` is not defined.

You could define `totalAds` as a [statistical relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) in your class e.g.

```
`totalAds` => array(self::STAT, 'Ad', array('id' => 'id'), 'condition' => ... , 'group' => ...)
```

You could then define your scope as:

```
'test' => array(
    'with' => array('totalAds'),
    'together' => true,
);
```

Alternatively, you can create a public variable `$totalAds` in your `Store` class which will then be assigned the value of `totalAds` from your query. However, this variable will not be automatically set outside of the `scope` without additional code.

Comment: bah, totally forgot, i've used public variables before for this issue. Personally i think it's an easier solution compared to adding it to my `relations()`. is there an advantage to adding it to relations?

Comment: Yeah. You will only need to use the scope where you need to eager load `totalAds`. If you only require this functionality in one place you can call it directly instead of using the scope.